# Json parsing in shell script

Tags: shell, curl, jq, github-api

I am trying to automate github repo creation. Below is my code:

```
pushtogithub() {
        git init
        git config user.name "user name"
        git config user.email "user email"
        git add .
        git commit -m "Initial commit"
        content=$(curl -s -u githubusername:githubaccesstoken https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$1", "private":true}')
        repo=$(jq -r '.ssh_url' <<< "${content}" )
        echo $repo created
        git remote add origin git@github.com:githubusername/$repo.git
        git push -u origin master
}
```

My github repo is always creating with `-1` name.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In the curl's request data, the `$1` is enclosed in single-quotes and won't be expanded. You can change that part into `-d "{\"name\":\"$1\", \"private\":true}"` for instance

Comment: That solves the repo creation with `-1` name. But still I am not getting correct values in `repo`. I am getting the literal value `echo jq -r...` into it.

Comment: The `echo` should be removed from the `jq` subshell, I assumed you had put it there to debug your command and forgot to remove it before posting here.

Comment: If you're going to use jq, use it right -- not just to *parse* JSON, but also to **create** JSON.

Comment: @Gulshan, ...if inserting content into JSON without using a syntax-aware encoder "works", you aren't testing with interesting enough data. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True that. I should have tried to use jq for creating the json as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
curl ... -d '{"name":"$1", "private":true}'
```

...with:

```
curl ... -d "$(jq -n --arg name "$1" '{"name": $name, "private": true}')"
```

That is to say: Nothing was wrong with how you were using `jq` to *parse* JSON; the problem is that you were trying to *create* JSON *without* using `jq`.

---

The simple-but-wrong way to try to fix this, by the way, would have been to change your quoting type:

```
#### DO NOT DO THIS
curl ... -d '{"name": "'"$1"'", "private": true}'
```

...or...

```
### DO NOT DO THIS EITHER
curl ... -d "{\"name\":\"$1\", \"private\":true}"
```

In the first example, we have everything *except* the `$1` surrounded in single quotes; but then end those single-quotes before your expansion, switch to a double-quoted context, expand `$1` there, and switch back.

In the second example, we just put the whole thing in double quotes, escaping the ones intended to be literal rather than syntactic.

Either approach, however, is *wrong*; try looking at what it does when your name is `Foo "The Leet" Bar` -- the literal quotes get conflated with JSON quotes, making the generated JSON invalid, unless you use a tool (like `jq`) that knows how to escape them.